# @Service is used to create service in CQ then what is use of BundleContext.registerService method?

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

How much different is a ComponentContext from a BundleContext because I see the getServiceReference method in both

Answer (score 2):

ComponentContext is defined by the declarative services spec and is taylored to work with DS components. It does not aim to provide all features of the Bundle Context.

If you need the BundleContext you can simply get it from the ComponentContext or even inject it into your @Activate method as a parameter.

Comment: Hi..ComponentContext is available using global.jsp while BundleContext is not??

Comment: I guess global.jsp is something CQ specific so I do not know details of it. If you can get the CompoentContext though then you can always retrieve the BundleContext from it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.. It resolves the base of the confusing structure in my problem

Comment: @prabhatGaur it seems like you are confusing some concepts. the word "Component" is used in more than one context. It could refer to an OSGi component (what Christian is talking about) or an AEM component used for content authoring (what you comment about the global.jsp)

Comment: Very much thanks @santiagozky. The global.jsp refers to com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.ComponentContext and not org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext I am still curious though about the use of registerService method

Answer (score 0):

Both registerService() and the @Service annotation allows you to create OSGi services. The difference is that BundleContext.registerService() uses plain OSGi API while the @Service annotation relies on OSGi Declarative Services.

When you use declarative services the entire life cycle of the Service is managed for you, if you register your service manually you need to do this yourself.

at the end, both mechanism provide you a way to create OSGi services. One is simpler, the other is more powerful.